# how to install Hibernate?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, installation

I am new to Hibernate in Java. I have downloaded the Hibernate-release-4.1.7.Final.zip file from the Hibernate.org site. Now how do I go about using it in my Java code? The IDE I am using is Eclipse Indigo. PS: The internet connection I am currently using isn't sufficient to install the software from Hibernate update site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below jars to the classpath, no installation required for Hibernate

```
antlr
asm-attrs
asm
cglib
dom4j
ejb3-persistence
hibernate-annotations
hiberate-common-annotations
hibernate-entitymanager
hibernate-validator
hibernate3
javassist
commons-beantils
commons-collections
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add hibernate jars to buildPath in eclipse.

Comment: the .zip file contains many .jar files. Which ones do I need to add in buildPath?

Comment: Its depend on your needs. http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/